# Is there any news about the Forgetoolkit?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have seen that the Forgetoolkit is no longer available via beta.autodesk.com .
I would be interested in how the Forgetoolkit will be used in the future. Is there a roadmap, will version 2.0 be released?

I would be pleased about a short statement.

Answer (score 0):

The current beta host - https://developer-api-beta.autodesk.io - is still available, but I can't answer whether or when the version 2.0 will be officially released...

If you're in need of a Forge-to-Unity pipeline, I'd suggest that you look at this library: https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-convert-utils. It converts the proprietary Forge file format to [glTF](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/tree/master/specification/2.0) which can then be loaded into Unity, Unreal Engine, as well as other platforms.

Comment: I know your work and I currently use forge-convert-utils (by the way, great work ) to display models in AR and VR because the models are too big for the Forgetoolkit.
I am currently thinking about developing a pipeline so that I can load the gltf models from the server at runtime.
Before I do that, I would be interested if the forgetoolkit is still being worked on.